Can I treat Gaussian Process Regression in the same way as simple regression in regards to the prediction?
I am learning Gaussian Process Regression.  I have two set-ups:
Setup 1:
$$
y = a + f_{1}(x_{1}) + f_{2}(x_{2}) + e
$$
where $  f_{1}() , f_{2}() $are kernels, say they are the separate squared exponential kernels (not actually important for the question).  $x_{1}, x_{2}$ are 2 independent variables, $a$ is an intercept and $e$ is the error term, distributed with mean = 0.
Setup 2:
$$
y = a + f(X) + e
$$
where in my case, $X$ is a $N$ x 2 matrix consisting of the same $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$.
If I want to predict $y$ when $x_{2}$ = 0, how can I do this in both setups correctly?  Is it the same as in simple regression?

Since a kernel is a function which takes two inputs and maps them to a single output, I suspect that $f_1,f_2$ are not actually meant to be kernels. Can you please flesh out your background a little bit? Maybe you can give us the reference you are using to define GPR?

@JohnMadden Setup1 is taken from this paper:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.07678 equation (15) to be exact.  The authors are using GP kernels to model non-linear effects on different x’s.

Most readers will not find time to read the mentioned manuscript and use it to make sense of your notation. Please extend add details to your question to clarify what you want to understand and make it as self-contained as possible.

@picky_porpoise May I ask what is unclear about my original question?  I only cited the paper because the other commenter asked for a reference.  I was not expecting anyone to need that.  But if I need to add any detail to my original question to make it self-contained, I am happy to give it a try.

What are the $f$s and what do you think a kernel is (see comment by John Madden)? What are $e$, $X$, $a$ etc. ?

@picky_porpoise I added clarifications.  But John Madden was not believing that f’s are separate kernels, so I provided him the reference he requested.
